# Adicionando itens dinamicamente no ClientDataSet

Tags: delphi

Como posso fazer para colocar o texto de um `TMemo` separado por ponto e vírgulas (;) como registros no `TClientDataSet`.

Exemplo:

> Código;Categoria;Frase;Autor
>
> 1;Motivacional;Frase 1;Autor 1
>
> 2;Provérbio;Frase 2;Autor 2
>
> 3;Ditado;Frase 3;Desconhecido

O que estou achando mais complicado é "recortar" a String a cada ponto e vírgula(;) e ler isso depois.

Acredito que o código vá seguir essa lógica:

```
for Linha := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
begin
  CDS.Insert;
  CDSCod.AsString       := {Código}
  CDSCategoria.AsString := {Categoria}
  CDSFrase.AsString     := {Frase} 
  CDSAutor.AsString     := {Autor}
  CDS.Post;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a helper da String para isto, declare nas uses a `System.StrUtils`.
Dessa forma você passa a ter acesso a diversas funções de auxilio.

Para o caso apresentado você utilizaria:

```
CDS.Insert;
CDSCod.AsString       := Memo.Lines.Strings[x].Split(';')[posicao_especifica]
CDSCategoria.AsString := Memo.Lines.Strings[x].Split(';')[posicao_especifica]
CDSFrase.AsString     := Memo.Lines.Strings[x].Split(';')[posicao_especifica]
CDSAutor.AsString     := Memo.Lines.Strings[x].Split(';')[posicao_especifica]
CDS.Post;
```

Caso o dataset em questão que esta utilizando não possui Indice definido você pode trocar o `.Insert` por `.Append` para ganhar na performance.

Edit: Lembrando que como String é um array, `posicao_especifica` começa com 0.

Comment: Deu erro aqui "There is no overloaded version of 'Split' that can be called with these arguments"

Comment: Versão da helper, modifique para `Split([';'])` a que você possui espera um array de de char.

Comment: Eu já tinha tentado usar `Split([';'])` mas continua dando erro.

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo, isto é muito básico para não funcionar.

Comment: Agora funcionou aqui. Muito obrigado.